# Celery 4 not auto-discovering tasks

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a Django 1.11 and Celery 4.1 project, and I've configured it according to the [setup docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html). My `celery_init.py` looks like

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings.settings'

app = Celery('myproject')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

#app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS) # does nothing
app.autodiscover_tasks() # also does nothing

print('Registering debug task...')
@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

However, when I launch a worker with:

```
.env/bin/celery worker -A myproject -l info
```

it shows no tasks being found except for the sample "debug_task", even though I have several installed apps with Celery tasks, with should have been found via the call to `app.autodiscover_task()`. This is the initial output my worker generates:

```
 -------------- celery@localhost v4.1.0 (latentcall)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.13.0-16-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial 2017-10-31 15:56:42
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         myproject:0x7f952856d650
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     amqp://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . myproject.celery_init.debug_task

[2017-10-31 15:56:42,180: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2017-10-31 15:56:42,188: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2017-10-31 15:56:43,211: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2017-10-31 15:56:43,237: INFO/MainProcess] celery@localhost ready.
```

All my legacy tasks in my app `tasks.py` files were defined like:

```
from celery.task import task

@task(name='mytask')
def mytask():
    blah
```

The docs suggest using the `shared_task` decorator, so instead I tried:

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def mytask():
    blah
```

But my Celery worker still doesn't see it. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I've been able to get tasks to show up by explicitly listing them in my setting's `CELERY_IMPORTS` list, but even then I have to heavily edit the `tasks.py` to remove all imports of my Django project (models.py, etc) or it raises the exception `Apps aren't loaded yet.` This is better than nothing, but requires a huge amount of refactoring. Is there a better way?

Comment: what happens when you run `celery worker -A app.tasks -l DEBUG`  I found I needed to specify an app's task file, not the project overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bigger problem was that Celery wasn't setting my custom `Celery()` instance as the current app. To fix it, I had to modify my `celery_init.py` to include:

```
from celery._state import _set_current_app

# setup my app = Celery(...)

_set_current_app(app)
```

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue, and the solution was to add the `include` kwarg to your celery call.

> The include argument is a list of modules to import when the worker starts. You need to add our tasks module here so that the worker is able to find our tasks.

```
app = Celery('myproject', 
             backend = settings.CELERY.get('backend'),
             broker = settings.CELERY.get('broker'),
             include = ['ingest.tasks.web', ... ])
```

Check out http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html#proj-celery-py for more information

Answer (score 4):

Just posting this here (I don't know why it works)

```
from django.conf import settings

app.config_from_object(settings, namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS, force=True)
```

`force=True` seems to be the solution

Another thing that works is calling `django.setup()` before instantiating celery.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os

import django

from celery import Celery


django.setup()  # This is key


# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('notifs')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

This method avoids `force=True`, import `django.conf.settings` and seems cleaner to me. Though i still have no idea why you need to call `django.setup` because It isn't stated in the docs.

Comment: `django.setup()` worked for me; 
`force=True` did not. Thanks for the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.conf import settings    
celery_app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

You can add the above line to make celery to autodiscover all tasks written in the whole project. This is working for me.

Comment: As stated in my post and my example code, I tried this and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Even i am not sure, if this will work. But i guess it worked for me:

There is a section in the same [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) you mentioned:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emzm7.png)

After this i removed CELERY_IMPORTS and it could register the tasks from all apps inside my project

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you have **class**-based tasks (CBT), like in our projects, those hacks above will still not work. For example:

```py
from celery.app.task import Task

class CustomTask(Task):

    def run(self):
        print('running.')
```

I found out that there are 2 solutions/workarounds:

1. [Register the task](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.0.0/whatsnew-4.0.html#the-task-base-class-no-longer-automatically-register-tasks) below the task class definition, and assign the task instance as the new global var:

   ```py
   from celery import current_app

   CustomTask = current_app.register_task(CustomTask())
   ```

   This is kinda disruptive though if you have lots of CBT, and the existing `CustomTask().apply_async()` calls should be converted to `CustomTask.apply_async()` since `CustomTask` is now an object/instance (previously a class name). Although a decorator could probably simplify the registration part.
2. Use the old/back-compatible base task class as the parent class instead of the `celery.app.task.Task`:

   ```py
   from celery.task import Task

   class CustomTask(Task):
       ...
   ```

   This seems deprecated in the [Celery 5.x](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/celery) codebase though. But at least it's the simplest solution for now (with Celery 4.x) before we upgrade.