# Celery doesn't detect and register tasks in django python

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task, periodic-task, django-celery-beat

I'm facing a problem where I can't set up periodic tasks in my application in django framework using Celery.

I've literally tried everything i could find adressing this issue on the internet, transfered the code from my MacOS laptop to the PC on Windows, but nothing seems to help... I used the documentation from celery to replicate every step for the periodic tasks to work, tried using other versions of Celery, Django-Celery-beat, django-celery-results, but nothing helped, so I don't know which part of code I'm wrong at.

Would very much appreciate any help!

**My apps packages versions:**

---

- celery                 5.3.6
- Django                 4.0.10
- django-celery-beat     2.5.0
- django-celery-results  2.5.1
- django-debug-toolbar   4.2.0
- honcho                 1.1.0
- mysqlclient            2.2.1
- oauthlib               3.2.2
- Pillow                 10.1.0
- pip                    23.3.2
- redis                  5.0.1
- **Python 3.8.8**

**My django project structure:**

```
django-project
├── .vscode
│   └── settings.json
├── myapp
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │      
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── signals.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── home.html
│   │   ├── login.html
│   │   └── skin_list.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
├── manage.py
├── django-project
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── celeryapp.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── pyenv.cfg
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
```

I didn't include some files to make project structure visually readable.

**Settings.py:**

```
"""
Django settings for Marketplace_backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

from django-project.config import * 

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


Debug=True 

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp', 
    'debug_toolbar',
    'social_django',
    'django_celery_beat',
    "django_celery_results",
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    "debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Marketplace_backend.urls'


# Celery Configuration
# CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
# CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'


from celery.schedules import crontab


# CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'test': {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.test',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
    },
}

# CELERY_INCLUDE = ('myapp.tasks',)
# CELERY_IMPORTS = ('myapp.tasks',)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
                'myapp.context_processors.user_social_data',
            ],
        },
    },
]


INTERNAL_IPS = [
    # ...
    "127.0.0.1",
    # ...
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django-project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'app_database',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',  
        'PORT': '3306',      
    }
}
```

**celeryapp.py:**

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab
import os
from django.conf import settings





app = Celery('django-project')


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django-project.settings')


app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

**init**.py in django-project inner folder:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celeryapp import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)

# Tried this line - didn't help.
from myapp.tasks import test
```

**tasks.py in myapp:**

```
# Someone suggested these two lines (2,3) - didn't help
import django
django.setup()


from celery import shared_task
from .models import *
from .views import *


@shared_task(name='test')
def test():
    return 'test'
```

I start everything via honcho Procfile:

```
web: python manage.py runserver
celery: celery -A django-project worker --pool=solo -l info
beat: celery -A django-project beat -l info
```

When I type **honcho start** (**start django server, celery worker, celery beat**), I get **this response**:

```
(django-project) (base) yanik@MacBook-Air django-project % honcho start
17:24:48 system   | web.1 started (pid=76511)
17:24:48 system   | celery.1 started (pid=76512)
17:24:48 system   | beat.1 started (pid=76513)
17:24:48 beat.1   | [2024-01-04 17:24:48,733: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
17:24:48 celery.1 |  
17:24:48 celery.1 |  -------------- celery@MacBook-Air.local v5.3.6 (emerald-rush)
17:24:48 celery.1 | --- * ----- 
17:24:48 celery.1 | -- *** ---- macOS-10.16-x86_64-i386-64bit 2024-01-04 17:24:48
17:24:48 celery.1 | - *** --- * --- 
17:24:48 celery.1 | -  ---------- [config]
17:24:48 celery.1 | -  ---------- .> app:         django-project:0x7f7a4603ca30
17:24:48 celery.1 | -  ---------- .> transport:   redis://127.0.0.1:6379//
17:24:48 celery.1 | -  ---------- .> results:     redis://127.0.0.1:6379/
17:24:48 celery.1 | - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
17:24:48 celery.1 | -- *** ---- .> task events: ON
17:24:48 celery.1 | --- * ----- 
17:24:48 celery.1 |  -------------- [queues]
17:24:48 celery.1 |                 .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
17:24:48 celery.1 |                 
17:24:48 celery.1 | 
17:24:48 celery.1 | [tasks]
17:24:48 celery.1 |   . django-project.celeryapp.debug_task
17:24:48 celery.1 | 
17:24:49 celery.1 | [2024-01-04 17:24:49,145: WARNING/MainProcess] /Users/yanik/.local/share/virtualenvs/django-project-9ZCnhA-p/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py:507: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
17:24:49 celery.1 | whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
17:24:49 celery.1 | If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
17:24:49 celery.1 | you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
17:24:49 celery.1 |   warnings.warn(
17:24:49 celery.1 | 
17:24:49 celery.1 | [2024-01-04 17:24:49,157: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://127.0.0.1:6379//
17:24:49 celery.1 | [2024-01-04 17:24:49,158: WARNING/MainProcess] /Users/yanik/.local/share/virtualenvs/Marketplace_backend-9ZCnhA-p/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py:507: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
17:24:49 celery.1 | whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
17:24:49 celery.1 | If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
17:24:49 celery.1 | you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
17:24:49 celery.1 |   warnings.warn(
17:24:49 celery.1 | 
17:24:49 celery.1 | [2024-01-04 17:24:49,161: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
17:24:49 web.1    | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
17:24:50 celery.1 | [2024-01-04 17:24:50,172: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
17:24:50 celery.1 | [2024-01-04 17:24:50,189: INFO/MainProcess] celery@MacBook-Air.local ready.
```

I get **this error**, when celery beat tries to execute periodic task:

```
20:04:00 beat.1   | [2024-01-01 20:04:00,000: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task  
20:04:00 beat.1   | test (myapp.tasks.test)
20:04:00 celery.1 | [2024-01-01 20:04:00,003: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'myapp.tasks.test'.
20:04:00 celery.1 | The message has been ignored and discarded.
20:04:00 celery.1 | 
20:04:00 celery.1 | Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
20:04:00 celery.1 | Or maybe you're using relative imports?
20:04:00 celery.1 | 
20:04:00 celery.1 | Please see
20:04:00 celery.1 | https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
20:04:00 celery.1 | for more information.
20:04:00 celery.1 | 
20:04:00 celery.1 | The full contents of the message body was:
20:04:00 celery.1 | b'[[], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (77b)
20:04:00 celery.1 | 
20:04:00 celery.1 | The full contents of the message headers:
20:04:00 celery.1 | {'lang': 'py', 'task': 'myapp.tasks.test', 'id': '332beab6-a3de-4e4a-84f3-59d6041a1b47', 'shadow': None, 'eta': None, 'expires': None, 'group': None, 'group_index': None, 'retries': 0, 'timelimit': [None, None], 'root_id': '332beab6-a3de-4e4a-84f3-59d6041a1b47', 'parent_id': None, 'argsrepr': '()', 'kwargsrepr': '{}', 'origin': 'gen24368@DESKTOP-KNKGMAO', 'ignore_result': False, 'replaced_task_nesting': 0, 'stamped_headers': None, 'stamps': {}}
20:04:00 celery.1 | 
20:04:00 celery.1 | The delivery info for this task is:
20:04:00 celery.1 | {'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery'}
20:04:00 celery.1 | Traceback (most recent call last):
20:04:00 celery.1 |   File "c:\users\yantb\desktop\django-project\django-project\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py", line 658, in on_task_received
20:04:00 celery.1 |     strategy = strategies[type_]
20:04:00 celery.1 | KeyError: 'myapp.tasks.test'
```

Comment: Compare `@shared_task(name='test')` and `KeyError: 'app_marketplace.tasks.test'`. If you provide a name then the celery worker should receive the name (just `test` not `'app_marketplace.tasks.test'`). How do you trigger the task?

Comment: Also, when you start a `celery worker` it should print all registered tasks. Could you attached them to your questions? Other thing, all celery tutorials name the python file with celery application just as `celery.py` not `celeryapp.py`. Maybe there is an issue.

Comment: Hey, @wiaterb! Thank you for your commenting! My mistake, I tried to switch the name of my app everywhere so it would be more understandable, but missed it in some parts of the code and of the response, so it stood the same 'myapp=app_marketplace'. I'll correct that now. Also, I don't really know why the worker receives 'app_marketplace.tasks.test'. I trigger the task via celery beat periodical tasks every minute ('CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE' parameter in settings.py). 'celeryapp.py' is the change I made on one suggestion from the forum, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Additionally, I've just added the `response` I get, when I start the server and `celery worker` + `celery beat`

Answer (score 0):

Can't actually explain the technical aspects of how does the celery cooperate with django, but it seems that it didn't detect django's settings module. That's why celery didn't detect tasks.
I made the changes suggested here: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/49538946/23181652**

Basically, I **modified celery worker** and **celery beat** launch commands, so the new **Procfile** for Honcho is:

```
web: python manage.py runserver
celery: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=django-project.settings celery -A django-project worker -l INFO 
beat: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=django-project.settings celery -A django-project beat -l info
```

And I **removed shared_task name** from **tasks.py**:

```
@shared_task
def test():
    return 'test'
```

And it worked!
Thanks @wiaterb for the inspiration for the analysis!